# ExtJS Data Grid Column renderer to have multiple values

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am wondering if it is possible in ExtJS to have several values of the data source available to the renderer of the column. For example with the "Actions" column, the id is passed to the renderer. However I require both the user_id and id passed to the render. How may I do this?

```
table_cols = [{
    header: "User ID",
    width: 30,
    sortable: true,
    dataIndex: 'user_id'
},
{
        header: "Actions",
        width: 60,
        sortable: false,
        dataIndex: 'id',
        renderer: function(val) {
               //IF USER ID MEETS A CONSTRAINT PRINT THE ID
         }
}];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know renderer function has several parameters:

```
     renderer: function(val, meta, record) {
           var userId = record.data.user_id;
     }
```

You can check the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer) for all the parameters